# What is the policy on archiving old questions?

Tags: feature-request

Could not seem to find what happens to really old questions, currently does everything stay or will less important questions eventually be deleted. Should SE maintain an archive of some sort?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everything pretty much stays around forever. There are a few exceptions - negative voted questions with no upvoted answers eventually disappear, for example. The rule of thumb is that everything 'useful' stays around. This is one of the reasons why we try to tag everything well and why we try to keep self-contained responses: we want people to be able to find the answers to their questions if they've already been asked here.